# How to add external jars in cassandra so as to use them in triggers

Tags: apache-kafka, jar, cassandra, triggers

I created a shadow jar which included Kafka-client library. But this jar fails to work when placed in $cassaandra_home/conf/trigger directory. Is there a way to add the external jar of Kafka separately and then link it to the main jar?

Answer (score 0):

It might have to be added to Cassandra's `CLASSPATH` environment variable.  You can do this by adding a line in the `cassandra-env.sh` file, referencing its location:

```
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/cassandra-ldap-3.11.4.jar"
```

The above line allows the use of [Instaclustr's Cassandra LDAP Authenticator](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-ldap), referencing it from within Cassandra's `lib/` dir (on each node).  Give that a try.

Comment: Should I add kafka-clients-2.1.0 jar in lib/ dir of cassandra ? And then I will have to restart nodes to make it work, right ?

Comment: @ArpitGupta Yes, that is what I would try.